# swift: UIPageViewController size

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UIPageViewController` with spine mid location. Now my 2 pages occupy the whole screen. But I want to change size of my flipping pages that I can create buttons in other part of controller. How to do it?

code:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var PageControl: UIPageControl!

    var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?
    var images = ["book1page1.png","book1","book1","book1page2.png","book1page1.png","book1page2.png"]
    var pendingIndex: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        createPageViewController()
        setupPageControll()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func createPageViewController() {
        // Instantiate the PageViewController
        let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        pageController.dataSource = self
        pageController.delegate = self

        if images.count > 0{
            let firstController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 0)!
            let contentControllers = [firstController]

            pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        pageViewController = pageController

        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController!)

        //self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
        self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, at: 0)
        pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

    }

    //Setup Pagination Icons and count
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return images.count
    }

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func setupPageControll(){
        let apperance = UIPageControl.appearance()
        apperance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.gray
        apperance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.white
        apperance.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    func currentControllerIndex() -> Int{
        let pageItemController = self.currentConroller()

        if let controller = pageItemController as? ContentViewController {
            return controller.itemIndex
        }
        return -1
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////

    func currentConroller() -> UIViewController?{
        if (self.pageViewController?.viewControllers?.count)! > 0{
            return self.pageViewController?.viewControllers![0]
        }

        return nil
    }

    func getContentViewController(withIndex index: Int) -> ContentViewController? {
        if index < images.count{
            let contentVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
            contentVC.itemIndex = index
            contentVC.imageName = images[index]

            return contentVC
        }

        return nil
    }

}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, willTransitionTo pendingViewControllers: [UIViewController]) {
        pendingIndex = (pendingViewControllers.first as! ContentViewController).itemIndex
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
        if completed {
            let currentIndex = pendingIndex
            if let index = currentIndex {
                self.PageControl.currentPage = index
            }

        }
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentViewController
        if contentVC.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex - 1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let contentVC = viewController as! ContentViewController
        if contentVC.itemIndex + 1 < images.count {
            return getContentViewController(withIndex: contentVC.itemIndex + 1)
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have instantiate `UIPageViewController` (id:"PageViewController") and add as subview inside the `UIViewController` so if you want create `UIButton` you can create but if its want to visible in front of this `UIPageViewController` You can put `self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, at: 0)` to says your `UIViewController` to put this subview at index `0` (means behind the every subviews)

Below I have given code: Add Subview at `index` `0` and Make Size of the `PageViewController` using `pageController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width - (5.0 * 20.0), height: self.view.frame.height - (2.0 * 50.0))` also Added two buttons calls "Next" and "Previous' at the bottom of `UIPageController`

Check Blow Code:

```
func createPageViewController() {
        let pageController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        pageController.isDoubleSided = true
        pageController.dataSource = self
        pageController.delegate = self

        if images.count > 1{
            let firstController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 0)!
            let secondController = getContentViewController(withIndex: 1)!
            let contentControllers = [firstController,secondController]
            pageController.setViewControllers(contentControllers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        pageViewController = pageController
        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
        self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, at: 0)

        pageController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: self.view.frame.width - (5.0 * 20.0), height: self.view.frame.height - (2.0 * 50.0))
        pageController.view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        pageController.view.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        pageViewController!.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        //Next Page Button
        let nextButton = UIButton()
        nextButton.frame = CGRect(x: pageController.view.frame.maxX - 75, y: pageController.view.frame.maxY + 5, width: 75, height: 50)
        nextButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        nextButton.setTitle("Next", for: .normal)
        nextButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionNext), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(nextButton)

        //Previous Page Button
        let previousButton = UIButton()
        previousButton.frame = CGRect(x: pageController.view.frame.minX, y: pageController.view.frame.maxY + 5, width: 75, height: 50)
        previousButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        previousButton.setTitle("Previous", for: .normal)
        previousButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionPrevious), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(previousButton)
    }

    @objc func buttonActionNext(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Next page")
    }

    @objc func buttonActionPrevious(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("Previous Page")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the frame

```
 pageViewController!.view.frame = ///
 self.view.insertSubview(pageViewController!.view, at: 0)
```